# How to integrate 'mathlive' in angular 14?

Tags: angular

I am developing a project using `Angular 14`. I want to add `mathlive` in my project. It is 100% match for one of my requirement. I tried multiple sources to find some information for implemention/integration in my project but nothing is working. It would be great if anyone can guide.

I have tried below steps provided on [https://cortexjs.io/mathlive/guides/integration/#npm][1]

1. Added mathlive using `npm install --save mathlive`.
2. Added below code in my ts file:

   ```
    import { MathfieldElement } from 'mathlive';const mfe = new MathfieldElement();
   ```

There is no any further step provided in the official documentation for adding this in template.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is working"? What exactly is not working? What exactly have you tried? What error is being thrown? When is being thrown? It seems their docs cover adding the library using npm. Reproduce your trials as [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TotallyNewb, I have gone through the official document. I did the installation of `mathlive` in my project and was trying to do below step:

import { MathfieldElement } from 'mathlive';
const mfe = new MathfieldElement();

but here only it started saying that mathlive is not having exported member 'MathfieldElement'.

Comment: @ChetanPurohit you need to provide a specific question. Nobody is going to help you with a complete guide not knowing any details. Please, add more detailed description of what did you try and what error did you get. To help troubleshooting you can also provide a code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out the solution. Below are the steps:

1. Import mathlive
   `import { MathfieldElement, Mathfield } from 'mathlive';`.
2. Add `ngAfterViewInit` hook in your component and add below code:

ngAfterViewInit(): void {

```
let mfe = new MathfieldElement();

// Set initial value and options
mfe.value = "\\frac{\\sin(x)}{\\cos(x)}";

// Options can be set either as an attribute (for simple options)...
mfe.setAttribute('virtual-keyboard-layout', 'dvorak');

// ... or using `setOptions()`
mfe.setOptions({
  virtualKeyboardMode: 'manual',
});

// Attach the element to the DOM
let mathLiveDiv = document.getElementById("mathLive");
mathLiveDiv.appendChild(mfe);}
```

Comment: Looks like we have a sample here for reference
https://github.com/syedabdulaala/mathlive-ng-sample/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @AkhilAravind, I have tried this sample and it is with old version which doesn't work with the latest version.